# DB Grade Field with numeric and text values SSRS

Tags: database, reporting-services

I have a table of examination grades that has a field with the final grade in it. The grade is either 9 - 1 or U. I am trying to run some stats on these grades but the U grade keeps making a mess of things and I get an error. We have a baseline value that I am trying to compare the final grade with. When the final grade is a U, the comparison value shows error. See image.

Any ideas what I need to do to handle this?

Kevin[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ8IC.png)

All sorts of combinations to handle it using either an IIF or a switch. The error remains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is due to the calculation trying to use the U. An IIF will try to evaluate both the true and false parts even when it won't use them.

I think the easiest way to handle this would be to create a Calculated Column on the dataset that converts the Award to a number so your current calculations work correctly.

[image]

The expression would convert the U to a 0 or whatever is needed, and might as well convert the field to a number too with CINT.

```
=IIF(Fields!Award.Value = "U", 0, CINT(Fields!Award.Value))
```